# networkInfo.IsConnected wont work in Xamarin android fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)this.Activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.ActiveNetworkInfo;
            bool isConnected = networkInfo.IsConnected;
```

this code is in the onCreateView method in my fragment and when i run the app i get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception:  
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred
```

it would be great if someone would explain to me what "not set to an instance of an object means" as i dont quite understand. still a little new to xamarin and c# in general.

heres the fragament1.cs file:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace TabsApp.Fragments
{
    public class Fragment1 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment1 NewInstance()
        {
            var frag1 = new Fragment1 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag1;
        }

        WebView webView;


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);

            webView = v.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);

            webView.LoadUrl("https://google.com");

            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            return v;
        }

        public void OnBackPressed()
        {
            webView.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

and heres the MainActivity.cs file:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using TabsApp.Fragments;
using Android.Content.PM;

using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

namespace TabsApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(false);

            }

            bottomNavigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);


            bottomNavigation.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected;

            LoadFragment(Resource.Id.menu_home);
        }

        private void BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadFragment(e.Item.ItemId);
        }

        void LoadFragment(int id)
        {

            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (id)
            {
                case Resource.Id.menu_home:
                    fragment = Fragment1.NewInstance();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.menu_audio:
                    fragment = Fragment2.NewInstance();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.menu_video:
                    fragment = Fragment3.NewInstance();
                    break;
            }
            if (fragment == null)
                return;

            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
               .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
               .Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that if you were to debug the above code and step through it, one of the variables would likely be NULL.

Comment: so how would I fix it?

Comment: Wait updating my answer as per your code

Comment: Which line gives this error? Have you set the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`? I have tested your code, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well its pretty simple this looks to me like you do not have your activity context here and for that reason you are unable to get the connMgr

What you need to do is when you call your fragment from your activity pass the current activity to your ~Fragment~ something like this on your fragment call:

```
Fragment1 newInstance(this);
```

Receive it in your fragment with something like this in your constructor:

```
public static AppCompatActivity _activity 
public static Fragment1 newInstance(AppCompatActivity activity )
{  
   _activity =activity ;

//Lines of code }
```

And in your onCreateView use it like this :

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)_activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.ConnectivityService);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.ActiveNetworkInfo;
        bool isConnected = networkInfo.IsConnected;
```

If it doesn't work lemme know!  Goodluck

Comment: sorry, i don't quite understand where to place the first 2 blocks of code

Comment: You are calling the fragment from an activity right?

Comment: What i mean here is you need to send the activity context to your fragment which you do by passing a this parameter to your fragment where you call its constructor.

Comment: ok, I have a confession. I downloaded a sample for a tabbed/fragment app and I worked off of that.. should've learnt to do it from the start. I don't know where the fragment constructor is called, I have added the mainactivity.cs file to the question and I hope you can point it out to me.

Comment: I have updated my answer check it out if correct mark it right. Goodluck

Comment: i get an error at `_activity = activity;` : `an object reference is required for the non-static field, property or method Fragment1._activity`

Comment: Just make that activity like in my updated answer @Hussam_alhassan

Comment: when i run the app i get an error at `bool isConnected = networkInfo.IsConnected;` : `Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred`

Comment: Wil check this out tomorrow morning for now cannot say anything